# Pptp только для связи

Tags: сеть, vpn, debian, windows-8

Всем доброго времени суток!
Есть небольшая задача, поднять VPN сервер для закрытого канала между офисом и одним пк за его приделами. Поднял сервер под дебианом pptpd. Включил forwarding в /etc/sysctl.conf
Сеть в офисе 192.168.1.0/24 для впн клиента выдается 192.168.1.240.
Так как трафик в офисе лимитируемый, есть такая проблема, как необходимость не предоставлять NAT для VPN клиента(windows).
Вопрос, как использовать VPN только как доступ к серверу?

Comment: наверное проблема в дефолтном роуте

Answer (score 2):

Если коротко: В таблице маршрутизации клиента должен быть только один маршрут ведущий в pptp-туннель, маршрут а подсеть 192.168.1.0/24 (кстати тут возможен конфликт с сетью клиента, например если он подключается через домашний роутер который использует для внутренней сети тот-же диапазон 192.168.1.0/24 (по умолчанию так делает большинство бытовых роутеров) по-этому я стараюсь не использовать 192.168.1.0/24 для своих сетей).

На практике: Просто не передавайте pptp-клиенту шлюз по-умолчанию (default gateway), только IP и маску подсети. Это либо в настройках DHCP сервера, либо в настройках PPTP сервера можно задать.

Answer (score 1):

Всё, не актуально, по крайней мере тестовая виртуалка с XP а борту - убрать галку в свойствах TCP/IP подключения. Либо как вариант - покопаться в дефолтных маршрутах, чтобы VPN был с метрикой <1 а локалка была с metric 1. Спасибо:)

Answer (score 1):

Ну... как получает инет удаленный комп я не знаю, офисная сеть 192.168.1.0/24 дана для примера.